# Update TableView through posted data from Spring Server

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, javafx, tableview

I am trying to make a game for my class project. The requirements are that I need to use a Spring architecture for both the server and client. I have done all that, I have even managed to post or get stuff from the server through RestTemplate.

My Server is completely on Spring Boot.
My Client is running on JavaFX and Spring Boot.

My problem now here is that sometimes I want the Server to post data to the client. The post is working, I am getting the data but I cannot seem to update the TableView in my screen.

I know that since the server is triggering this on the client side, it must not be on the main JavaFX UI Thread. So I tried loading the FXML

```
gameDetails = playerView;
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("pre_game.fxml"));
    try {
        Parent root = loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PreGame controller = loader.getController();
    TableView<PlayerView> tblPlayerList = controller.tblPlayerList;
    TableColumn<PlayerView, String> colPlayerName = controller.colPlayerName;
    ObservableList<PlayerView> gamesObservableList = controller.gamesObservableList;
    gamesObservableList.clear();
    gamesObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(gameDetails);
    tblPlayerList.setItems(gamesObservableList);
```

But nothing happens on the screen.

On the server side, I am posting a list of "Players" to any clients. It works, I am receiving the data correctly. All that is a problem is that I cannot understand how to update the TableView since I don't have access to the main UI Thread.

Comment: Can you display the data if you just hard code it, instead of loading it from the server?

Comment: I am getting a list containing objects of the following nature:

`public PlayerView(String id, String name, String clientUri, String robotName, String secret) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.clientUri = clientUri;
        this.robotName = robotName;
        this.secret = secret;
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **initialize** function of my JavaFX controller, I need to add the following line:

```
controller_name = this;
```

And outside the **initialize** function a declaration of the controller object like:

```
public static ControllerName controller_name;
```

So then when the Spring server tries to contact my UI, I can access my UI element through:

```
controller_name.ui_element_name
```

Provided that I may have to also use Platform.RunLater to update the UI as it's not on the JavaFX thread.